# How to identify elements on Java swing application?

Tags: swing, automation, automated-tests, winium, ui-spy

I am trying to automate java swing application using `Winium`. To identify properties of elements I have used `UISpy.exe` and `Inspect.exe`. But both are failed to identify elements on my swing application. However, both are working when I am trying to identify elements on Windows Notepad application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a bit research for testing swing application.

Winium is not one of them.

**Supported Platforms**

```
Windows Desktop (WPF, WinForms) Apps
Windows Store or Universal Apps for Windows Phone
Windows Phone Silverlight Apps
```

Try with

[AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-swing.html)

[Sikuli](https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli)

Answer (score 0):

To automate swing ui in Java, [Jemmy](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Jemmy_Tutorial) is the good option.

Even the same one is available as [RobotFramework](http://robotframework.org/) keyword library in the name [SwingLibrary](http://robotframework.org/SwingLibrary/SwingLibrary-1.9.2.html).